# How to delete info in the middle of a txt file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I want to delete some info inside a txt file for example:
This is the txt before

```
kaspersen@outlook.com| Kristoffer Kaspersen| Cypernsvej| 30, 1| 2300 Kobenhavn| Denmark| 30935414
andrew@duesbury.ca| Andrew Duesbury| 1545 Portsmouth Pl| Mississauga ON L5M 7W1| Canada| +16478975695
won@cloudzndirt.com| Won Oh| 11149 Camarena Ave| MONTCLAIR CA 91763| United States| 9999999999
```

This is after

```
kaspersen@outlook.com| Kristoffer Kaspersen| Denmark| 30935414
andrew@duesbury.ca| Andrew Duesbury| Canada| +16478975695
won@cloudzndirt.com| Won Oh|United States| 99999999999
```

basically like deleting info between the the 2nd '|' and the 4th '|'

this was the code that I started with

```
f = open("Extracts.txt", "r")

x = f.readline()
print(x)
a=0
for i in x:
    if i =="|":
        a+=1
        if a ==2:
```

here in this code I tried to count the | it did work but I wasn't quite sure how to tell the program to delete until reaching the 4th |.

Comment: have you tried reading with pandas.read_csv() and using the .drop() method to drop the column?

Comment: I recommend getting rid of the extra whitespace. Will make reading via `csv` easier in the future.

Comment: never worked with csv before i think I should take a look at it\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use `split`:

```py
with open("Extracts.txt", "r") as f, open("output.txt", "w") as g:
    for line in f:
        fields = line.split('|')
        print(*fields[0:2], *fields[-2:], sep='|', end='', file=g)
```

`output.txt`:

```
kaspersen@outlook.com| Kristoffer Kaspersen| Denmark| 30935414
andrew@duesbury.ca| Andrew Duesbury| Canada| +16478975695
won@cloudzndirt.com| Won Oh| United States| 9999999999
```

Comment: how can save it to another txt file  can I write the lines directly to another file

Comment: ohhhhh where can find docs that gives all these details.

Comment: @Paties It involves `split`, slicing, `with`, `open`, and `print`. I believe you can find them in https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html.

Comment: what if i want to add like the date of today before the last number?